# STM32F411 MCU with MCP25625 connection

Tags: stm32

I have a custom board with a `STM32F411` and a `MCP25625` chip, which I did not create. But now I need to write a firmware on it so that this board communicates with another board via the CAN bus. I know on which pins the `MCP25625` is connected to the mcu. But I cannot find libraries and examples of how they can be connected programmatically so that the CAN bus can work. The only library that I have found is `CANnuccia`, but it seems to me that it will not work for this case, and even more so, I have not found any examples using this library. Well, the question itself - which library should be used in this case and how to link them programmatically. (I already know how to upload firmware to this board, write PWM to it, etc.). Most likely this question will not be correct for this site, but I hope for any help and advice. Thank you.

Comment: Arduino should have libraries. Have you looked there?

Comment: Im using STM32CubeIDE, should I use Arduino IDE?

Comment: That's your choice. I'd use platformio, but that's mine. The choice of IDE is not the issue - you want library code. Does cubemx not have any CAN libraries?

Comment: Im not sure about how to check this out. But I do not see any CAN libraries in my project.

Comment: Ok, you're not using the F411's can controllers. A quick Google found this: https://github.com/coryjfowler/MCP_CAN_lib

Comment: I have found this one https://github.com/eziya/STM32_SPI_MCP2515 then I put these files into my project. The project starts, but when I try to get data from the CAN bus, it just returns an array of zeros. Although, from the second device I send data with ID 512, and on this board I don't have any filters, so it should see these messages. I would be grateful for any advice.

Comment: All I can suggest is you use the debugger and step through the code. It is hard to remotely debug conplex systems.

Comment: I understand. Anyway, thanks for your answers.